# AWS Lambda getting SSLException while calling third party endpoints

Tags: aws-lambda, endpoint, sslexception

Thanks in advance for your support,

We developed our schedulers (Listeners) on AWS Lambda serverless, and some of our lambda functions are calling multiple third party endpoints to retrieve data and save them in our database.
some of the endpoints call are working fine without any additional steps todo, but some of them are returning the following SSL problem

```
I/O error on POST request for "https://endpoint/requestName": readHandshakeRecord; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
```

We tried to follow the following article in order to solve the SSL problem
**https://dev.to/leading-edje/aws-lambda-layer-for-private-certificates-465j** .

But after uploading the certifications in AWS Layers from the console (portal) and assigning it to the lambda function and adding the certification path in the environment variable, the SSL exception sometimes disappear and sometimes no, so we are not able to find a solution.
In addition we could not find any simple or example on how to add multiple certificates,
but we were trying to separate the certifications by adding two points ":" between each certification path in the environment variable path. (but still not working)
I found the two point separation from this AWS article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html
Image:
[image]

Kindly advice on how to add multiple certificate paths in AWS lambda.

AWS console Layers and environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE image example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed,
After adding the memory size, lambda stopped throwing this SSLException,
So the problem was that lambda was not able to finish all the third party calls because the memory was not enough.

In addition, timeout should be increased also because if a third party request is taking time to finish Lambda is re-calling the third party automatically.